# How to set a property value of a class using firebase nested query?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, final

I have a firebase data structure like this
[Firebase JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHQ1F.jpg)

Inside Oli reference there is a "kategori" key (-Ky0RUaYOgB6gks2t3oY) which is having same value as a child in Kategori reference (-Ky0RUaYOgB6gks2t3oY). I'm trying to retrieve all data from Oli reference and set its value to an arraylist using item as DataOli class.

```
mDbRefOli.orderByChild("nama").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                final DataOli item = new DataOli();
                item.setIdOli(childDataSnapshot.getKey());
                item.setNamaOli(childDataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue().toString());
                mDbRefKategori.child(childDataSnapshot.child("kategori").getValue().toString()).child("nama").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        item.setKategoriOli(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                mDbRefMerk.child(childDataSnapshot.child("merk").getValue().toString()).child("nama").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        item.setMerkOli(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
                item.setJenisOli(Integer.parseInt(childDataSnapshot.child("jenis").getValue().toString()));
                item.setHargaOli(Integer.parseInt(childDataSnapshot.child("harga").getValue().toString()));
                item.setKapasitasOli(Double.parseDouble(childDataSnapshot.child("kapasitas").getValue().toString()));
                mListOli.add(item);
            }
            mAdapterOli.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mSwlOli.setRefreshing(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
```

Instead getting that key and displaying it to user, **I'm trying to get "Matic" value from a child (-Ky0RUaYOgB6gks2t3oY) in Kategori reference** along with this code `item.setKategoriOli(dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class));` to set kategori name in item class. **At the end I can't get that "Matic" value, instead I was get null value**.

Maybe this problem happened, because AS requires me to define final in item class at the beginning and I'm trying to set kategori value inside another inner class. Can you help me to solving this problem?

Comment: What exactly do you want to retrieve?

Comment: @PeterHaddad All data in Oli reference (ID, nama, kategori, merk, etc) but I also want to get some value in kategori reference (like "Matic") instead of kategori value in Oli's data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//declare the Strings before


DatabaseReference newtables = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Oli");
newtables.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            values = dataSnapshot.child("harga").getValue().toString();
jenis=dataSnapshot.child("jenis").getValue().toString();
kap=dataSnapshot.child("kapasitas").getValue().toString();
kat=dataSnapshot.child("kategori").getValue().toString();
merk=dataSnapshot.child("merk").getValue().toString();
nama=dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue().toString();
            DatabaseReference 
joins=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Kategori");
joins.orderByKey().equalTo(kat).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        retrieve = dataSnapshot.child("nama").getValue().toString();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

You can do this, its like a `join` first you retrieve data from one node and then you use the `id` and query on it and get the data in the other node.

Comment: how to assign value to string I've defined in the beginning within inner class (like onChildAdded), java requires me to using final before declaring the strings?

Comment: I didnt understand, in the answer that I posted im retrieving the data from the database.. you should send the data to the database in another query, yes you have to use final @Yoel

Comment: Actually I've got all datas, but I must set it to a class and put the class inside an arraylist.

Comment: @Yoel you are getting matic as null since you are referencing a wrong location

Comment: inside joins class I can get kategori value as matic, then I put it into a string let say it String mKategori. But when I'm trying to get mKategori's value in newtables class it becomes null. That's what I'm asking for

Comment: @Yoel, why would you do that? First you get all the data under `Oli`, which is in the code above `newtables`, then in another query that is inside the top query you reference location of the other node and use the `String kat` as a condition to be able to retreive all the data in the other table

Comment: Because I want to get data for DataOli class like this {
id : -Ky6mGwJVeGZa5modBvJ,
nama : MPX 2,
kategori : matic,
...
}

Comment: @Yoel in the first query `newtables` you are already get that data.. nama/harga/jenis.. but you get `kategori` equal to the id as in your database. Then in the query below it, you use that `id` to check if it is found in the other node and get `nama: matic`. But if you want `kategori:matic` in node `Oli` then what is the point of having an `id` in the database, you wont be able to do `kategori: matic`. The above code works according to the database provided. So, `kategori:id` then use that `id` to get value of nama(matic) in other node

Comment: I got it what you're meaning but later if I want to have 3 query like first query to retrieve all Oli's data and second query to retrieve Kategori data which matches in Oli's kategori node and third query to retrieve Merk data which matches in Oli's Merk node. Is it possible?

Comment: @Yoel yes use the concept in my answer and always use `ids`, example you make a random id using push then you use that id somewhere else in another node, then retrieve that id to be able to do something close to a concept of a `join`, but it will only work with `ids`